# Jquery plugin affecting multiple divs same way

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a little jquery plugin, but the problem I get is that if I call it a few times for a few different divs, the last call overrules all others and I get that last result on each div.

```
<div class="p1"><p>text 1</p></div>
<div class="p2"><p>text 2</p></div>
<div class="p3"><p>text 3</p></div>
```

JS:

```
var changeColor = {

    init: function(options, elem) {
    var self = this;

    self.elem = elem;

    self.options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.changeColor.options, options );

    self.blueColor();
    },

    blueColor: function() {
    var self = this;

    $('p').css('color', self.options.color);
    }

};

$.fn.changeColor = function( options ) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var color = Object.create( changeColor );

            color.init( options, this );

            $.data( this, 'changeColor', color );
        });
    };

$.fn.changeColor.options = {
    color: 'green'
};

(function() {

$('.p1').changeColor({color: 'yellow'});
$('.p2').changeColor({color: 'blue'});

})();
```

Now both `<p>` in both divs will be blue, instead of the first one being yellow and the second blue.

Comment: You have var self = this;  twice in your code!

Comment: Might it be easier to use CSS and apply classes with your function?

Comment: @roasted thanks for noticing, this was just a quicky I wrote to get the point across :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the color style to all `<p>` elements when you do `$('p')`. Apply the changes only to the selected element by using `$(self.elem)`.

Change this

```
$('p').css('color', self.options.color);
```

For this

```
$(self.elem).css('color', self.options.color);
```

You can see a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4Wgq/), this portion of the code is at line 16.

**EDIT:** As very well pointed out by [skafandri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1308134/skafandri) this changes the `<div>` color, not `<p>`'s. To change the color of the paragraph change your selector:

```
$('.p1 p').changeColor({color: 'yellow'});
$('.p2 p').changeColor({color: 'blue'});
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4Wgq/2/).

Comment: This will change the **div** color, I would say `$(self.elem).find('p').css('color', self.options.color);`

Comment: @skafandri, you are right. However to apply the changes to the `<p>` element I'd rather select the element outside the plugin.
`$('.p1 p').changeColor({color: 'yellow'});` This way the plugin isn't only bound to div's with a paragraph inside.

Comment: I just wanted to tie to the OP question context :)  
I would not use a plugin to change a CSS color :D

Comment: @Telmo that is exactly what I did. Anyway, my q has been cleared. Thanks!